# C# a function with one argument of type T that returns a function with one argument of type T, but in fact needs more arguments

Tags: c#, recursion, functional-programming, delegates

I have a `Dictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>>` that encodes a tree:
The keys represent all nodes of the tree and the values are the children of the corresponding nodes.
If a node does not have children, then its value is an empty enumerable.

E.g. the following mapping `treeMap` with `T = int` would be such a mapping that encodes a tree:

```
treeMap[1] = { 2, 3, 4 }
treeMap[2] = { 5, 6 }
treeMap[3] = { 7 }
treeMap[4] = { }
treeMap[5] = { }
treeMap[6] = { }
treeMap[7] = { 8 }
treeMap[8] = { }
```

I want to write a method `UseFunctionOnTree(T node, Dictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> treeMap, Function F)` that apllies `F` to the given node, gets a new function `newF` from the old `F` and the `node`, and applies `newF` to all children.

This is as far as I got:

```
public class MapHelper<T>
{
    public delegate Function Function (T element);

    public static void UseFunctionOnTree(T node,
                           Dictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> treeMap, Function F)
    {
        Function newF = F(node);
        foreach (T child in treeMap[node])
            UseFunctionOnTree (child, treeMap, newF);
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I don't know how to define such a `Function`.
I could define it like this:

```
public Function Useless(T element)
{
    DoSthWith(element);
    return Useless;
}
```

But I don't know how to define a function that returns something other than itself!

One of my use cases is the following:
I have a tree of type `MyObject`, where `MyObject` may look like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int index;
}
```

I take some `int`-valued offset, let's say `firstOffset = 3`. I want `Function` to add `offset` to `node` (i.e. to its `index`). Then I want to add an offset to all children of `node`, but this time the offset should be `nextOffset = firstOffset + node.index`.

Here is the pseudocode of what I want:

```
public Function AddOffset(T element)
{
    int firstOffset;
    // somehow make firstOffset = 3

    int newOffset = firstOffset + element.index;
    element.index = newOffset;
    return AddOffset // but this time with the new offset
}
```

How do I do this? I feel like it might be solvable by some lambda statement...

Do I need more arguments? From the intuitive point of view, I don't.
E.g. we have

`node1` with `node1.index = 1` and

`node2` with `node2.index = 100`.

We have `F` given as
"Add 3 to the index of your argument and store that number as `n`. Return a function that is like this one but adds `n` to the index of its argument."

From that we get that `F(node1)` will change `node1.index` to `3+1=4` and add `4` to its argument's index and consequently, `(F(node1))(node2)` will change `node2.index` to `4+100=104` and add `104` to it's argument's index. And `((F(node1))(node2))(node1)` will change `node1.index` to `104+4=108` and add `108` to its argument's index, and so on.

Also I'd like to note that I do not always have the case of needing/changing one `int` parameter. It might be that I need several parameters, and their type can also vary on what concrete problem I want to solve. So it would be nice if I do not have to decide in advance how many (and of what type) parameters I need. It should all be contained in the `Function` itself.

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Wait, do you mean a function of type T that requires a function of type T that returns a function of type T that requires a function of type T and returns a function of type T that returns a function that requires a function that returns a function of type T? Or vice versa?

Comment: Please note that you defined `index` as `double`, later on you're using it like an `int`.

Comment: Please note also that you can not modify the tree structure with this! As you store tree nodes in a map, you can not change the tree structure (nodes and children) via changing some index values because the `Dictionary` does assume that the hashcode of the contained keys remains unchanged!

Comment: @ventiseis I corrected the double to int. For the hashcode thing, let's just assume that it is defined by some other fields that are never changed. But thanks for the hint, I overlooked this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define an auxiliary function

```
public static Function MakeAddOffset(int offset)
{
    return element => {
        int newOffset = offset + element.index;
        element.index = newOffset;
        return MakeAddOffset(newOffset);
    };
}
```

and then use `MakeAddOffset(3)` as the `AddOffset` function.  (You can generalize this from `AddOffset` to any function `F` by defining a similar auxiliary function `MakeF` in the same manner as `MakeAddOffset`.)

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind (although not clear enough to be able to write it down)! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this but I would not recommend it. Please have another thought about your algorithm and data structure in use. Personally, I would use a more object oriented approach, but let's try it.

The first abstraction would be to represent the data which use a manipulating with another generic type `Q`:

```
public class MapHelper<T, Q> {
     // (insert the following code here)
}
```

At first, we need some more delegates to represent your mapping:

```
    public delegate Q Getter(T element);
    public delegate void Setter(T element, Q value);
    public delegate Q Operation(Q left, Q right);
```

The `Getter` allows us to retrieve the index, the `Setter` can write new values and the `Operation` here is a simple addition. We need this functions when we are applying our mapping function:

```
    public static void UseFunctionOnTree(T node,
                           Dictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> treeMap, Function F, Getter g, Setter s) {
        Function newF = F(node, g, s);
        if (!treeMap.ContainsKey(node)) return;
        foreach (T child in treeMap[node])
            UseFunctionOnTree(child, treeMap, newF, g, s);
    }
```

Now we can define `GenericAddOffset` which uses the declared delegates and a *closure* to define a new lambda function:

```
    public static Function GenericAddOffset(T element, Getter g, Setter s, Operation o, Q left) {
        Q newOffset = o(left, g(element));
        s(element, newOffset);
        return (T element1, Getter g1, Setter s1) => {
            return GenericAddOffset(element1, g1, s1, o, newOffset);
        };
    }
```

This is the link you're missing: closures allow you to define function using variables from the outer scope.

At last, I defined a helper function:

```
    public static void PrintTree(Dictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> tree, Getter g) {
        foreach (var value in tree) {
            Console.Write("[" + g(value.Key).ToString() + "]: ");
            foreach (var node in value.Value)
                Console.Write(g(node).ToString() + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Now, with:

```
using Helper = MapHelper<MyObject, int>;
```

we can write the following example program:

```
class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var tree = new Dictionary<MyObject, IEnumerable<MyObject>>();
        Helper.Getter g = t => (int)t.index;
        Helper.Setter s = (t, o) => { t.index = o; };

        var root = new MyObject();
        var node1 = new MyObject();
        var node2 = new MyObject();
        s(root, 1);
        s(node1, 1);
        s(node2, 100);
        tree.Add(root, new[] { node1, node2 });

        Helper.PrintTree(tree, g);

        Helper.UseFunctionOnTree(root, tree,
            (t, g1, s1) => { return Helper.GenericAddOffset(t, g1, s1, (x, y) => x + y, 3); }, g, s);

        Helper.PrintTree(tree, g);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

*Output*:

```
[1]: 1 100

[4]: 5 104
```